# Access Denied on Install Symfony on Xamp?

Tags: symfony, xampp

I am new in Symfony and dont know how to install Symfony on my Xamp server. In symfony webm, when i want to download it, Through this command `` c:> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony` ``
then Access denied is occur on my cmd.
[image]

Comment: do you have access to c:\ directory?

Comment: yes its my own laptop.

Comment: but do you have access privileges (can you create file in c:\), by default when you run cmd you don't have root privileges

Comment: Have you tried opening cmd in administrator mode?

Comment: Yes i have facing this error **Php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**

Comment: Yes the file is created through cmd without Administrator Access too.

Comment: If you get a "not recognized command" with an Admin shell on windows, maybe you've set the php command on the user path instead of the system path.

Answer (score 0):

I am also beginner to symfony and had a same problem.
I think you also need to install composer first to make it working. I download the composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and then installed it. After that the symfony installer command worked for me. Try it and Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, it was not allowing me to download the `symfony` file (and displaying "Access denied") because I had a folder named `Symfony`. Renaming the folder solved the project problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not have write access to your c:\ directory - it is default settings on Windows 7, 8, ....
Create some folder (for ex. c:\symfony_project) and try `readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony` in that folder

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still facing the problem, here how I solved mine. First you have to open XAMPP as administrator by clicking right click on XAMPP make sure its closed first after opening it as admin enable Apache and mysql then open shell, then head to htdocs and make sure there is composure installed and then paste the installing of symfony there. I hope it works after that.